# How to maintain scroll offset in the nested listviews

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm constructing a nestedlistview(horizontal listviews inside a sliverlist)inside my app.while scrolling the vertical sliverlist,the horizantal listviews going back to their starting position if i scroll past them,is there a way to maintain the offset for every horizontal listview

i have given a key and scroll controller to every horizontal listview and set the property keepscrolloffset true but that didn't work.